# Where can I check online if the Romanian consulate in New York has my passport ready?

Tags: romanian-citizens

I went to [the Romanian consulate in NYC](https://newyork.mae.ro/en/node/409) to renew my passport. They gave me a link to check if the passport was ready to be picked up, but I've lost the link.

Where can I check the status of my passport renewal online?

Comment: This seems more of an [Expatriates.SE] question.

Comment: Yes, I already know my passport is ready for pick-up! What I'm asking... do I need to set up an appointment to physically pick it up at the consulate? OR are there hours during which I can pick it up? I see no information online regarding that and I cannot reach anyone at the consulate to as.

Comment: @phoog Arguably it's both. Travel does entertain questions about getting a passport in your own country (presumably because passports are used for travelling). The same logic still applies even if you happen to be an expatriate.

Comment: @Relaxed that's why I didn't say "this question belongs on Expatriates."  In theory, anyone on a temporary visit to the US cannot be admitted beyond the expiration date of their passport, though of course passports sometimes require replacement for reasons other than having expired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page is http://newyork.mae.ro/cauta-pasaport

It requires your Romanian Personal Numeric Code, and your initial.